# Cancel button callback

Tags: add-on

My addon code calls `result = bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`.

How can I understand, that user pressed `Cancel` button? I think, that result will be `{'CANCELLED'}`, but result is `{FINISHED}`.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing here, but I would say it does “finished” instead of “cancelled” because otherwise it would never return the “finished” callback. If the user didn’t cancel, blender quits, and the script is aborted. There is no reason for it to return “cancelled” to the script, because it would be equivalent to telling the script it’s still alive.

Comment: Ok. So how can I understand that user pressed ```Cancel```?

Comment: @Multifora it returns “finished” instead of the script stopping.